# Filling child entity with Entity Framework SqlQuery

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have two entities in 1:n relationship: Category and Product.

```
public class Category 
{
   public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public virtual Product { get; set; }
}

public class context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Its possible to load products in every category by Eager loading.

```
context.Categories.Include(c=>c.Products).ToList()
```

How can I load products in every category in below query same as Eager loading?

```
var q = @"
   SELECT Categories.*
   JOIN Products
   ON Category.CategoryId = Products.CategoryId";
var c = context.Categories.SqlQuery(q).ToList();
```

Its only a simple query. I need to use SqlQuery to execute some queries.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907) you can't:

> the query should be written to ensure that it *only* returns entities that are really *of the requested type*

(my emphasis)

So it's only by lazy loading (if enabled) that you can load the `Products` of the categories *after* the `SqlQuery` has run, which will cause n+1 queries.

Comment: For everyone else off Google, I want to make sure that they understand that `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>()` isn't the same as `dbContext.TableName.SqlQuery()`. The difference is that you're calling it on `Database` and feeding it a type, rather than a table and no type. Confused me a fair bit.

Comment: @TankorSmash so can this be done using the `dbcontext.database.sqlquery` version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to materialize entities obtained from Sql query if the result contains multiple entity types.