# MVC4 Stored Procedure returns results, but MVC shows the lookup field values are null

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-4

My proc returns all results but MVC is showing the lookups are null.

I have a VIEW where the "grid" for loop looks like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Headline, "ViewDetails", "Advisory", new { id=item.AdvisoryId }, "")</td>
        <td>@item.AdvisoryStartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@item.AdvisoryType.AdvisoryType</td>
        <td>@item.AdvisoryProvider.AdvisoryProvider</td>
        <td>@item.AdvisoryCategory.AdvisoryCategory</td>         
    </tr>
}
```

The last three fields are lookups.  I initially populated this with this controller call:

```
var advisories = db.Advisories.Include(i => i.AdvisoryType)
            .Include(i => i.AdvisoryProvider)
            .Include(i => i.AdvisoryCategory)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.AdvisoryStartDate);
        ViewData["Advisories"] = advisories;
```

But I've now replaced that with this proc call (because I need to get "advisories" the user hasn't seen yet, so it's more complicated than the above, which is basically "get all"; I also need to query the DB by UserID whereas MVC only has User.Identity.Name):

```
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Advisory>("EXEC [ponzi].[uspUserAdvisories] {0}",  User.Identity.Name).ToList();
ViewData["Advisories"] = results;
```

I know the proc returns all results (when I run it in SQL Server), but in MVC, when I mouse over "results", the AdvisoryCategoryID is filled in but AdvisoryCategory is null.  Same with the other two lookups.  I assume it's because AdvisoryCategoryID is in my Advisory model, but AdvisoryCategory is from the AdvisoryCategory model.

Here is the relevant part of the Advisory model:

```
[Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AdvisoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual int AdvisoryTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual AdvisoryTypes AdvisoryType { get; set; }

    public virtual AdvisoryProviders AdvisoryProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual int AdvisoryProviderID { get; set; }

    public virtual AdvisoryCategories AdvisoryCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual int AdvisoryCategoryID { get; set; }
```

How can I get these three lookup fields to show the data returned by the proc? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: ViewModels.  Relevant portion of the new AdvisoriesViewModel here (to replace my Advisories model):

```
    public int AdvisoryTypeID { get; set; }
    public string AdvisoryType { get; set; }

    public string AdvisoryProvider { get; set; }
    public int AdvisoryProviderID { get; set; }

    public string AdvisoryCategory { get; set; }
    public int AdvisoryCategoryID { get; set; }
```

Now I call my proc with this line, having replaced "Advisory" with "AdvisoryViewModel":

```
var advisories = db.Database.SqlQuery<AdvisoryViewModel>("EXEC [ponzi].[uspUserAdvisories] {0}", User.Identity.Name).ToList();
```

Since the returned data set has a model with the same fields, and which aren't relying on another model, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about the `eager loading of navigation properties` (`AdvisoryCategory` etc), if I understand properly what you're trying to do...

> If you're trying to load `navigation properties` - from your SQL query, SP - I don't think that'd work. That's the `Include` part of the normal linq statement above - and that generates
>   an more complex SQL to join in other table's properties etc. It gets
>   more complicated with more of it.

That doesn't work for code-first and even if it would requires special 'techniques' to get it to match.

See this link here for the confirmation [Eager Load from Entity Framework SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115845/eager-load-from-entity-framework-sp/13118282#13118282)

You can try setting it to `lazy loading` by default (virtual etc.) - and hope it'd load on first access. Also try different [loading methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9138508/417747).

**Or just explicitely load on demand** sort of - see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) and `Explicitly Loading`.

---

[Eager Load from Entity Framework SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115845/eager-load-from-entity-framework-sp/13118282#13118282)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232
[Eager loading in EntityFramework with DbContext.Database.SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136923/eager-loading-in-entityframework-with-dbcontext-database-sqlquery/9138508#9138508)