# How can I Include child data using SqlQuery in EF 6?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 in MVC and have a query like this to get all my articles and then the category that the article is listed under. This returns results:

```
list = db.Articles.Where(a => a.PublishDate <= DateTime.Now)
           .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublishDate)
           .Skip(page * ArticleCount)
           .Take(ArticleCount)
           .Include(a => a.Category).ToList();
```

I also have a filtered query by category or subcategory which I have as a stored procedure. I'm using `SqlQuery`. The Category model isn't loaded in and `Include` doesn't work. I can't seem to find any examples online that relate to EF 6 using code first. How can I pull in the category data?

```
list = db.Database.SqlQuery<Article>(
               "sp_GetArticlesByCategory @category, @subcategory", 
               new SqlParameter("@category", category),
               new SqlParameter("@subcategory", subcategory))
           .Skip(page * ArticleCount)
           .Take(ArticleCount)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Don't think it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13039222/1663001

Answer (score 1):

The following is not preciselly an answer to the question: *How can I Include child data using SqlQuery in EF 6?*

But based on the explanation and the question: **why do you need a stored procedure ?**, I show the following:

if you need a tracked entity this can be done by using [eager loading multiple levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels).

```
from a in db.Articles.Include("Category.SubCategory")
where a.Category.SomeProperty == someValue
select a
```

But if not, you can use a DAO object and use a linq query

```
from a in db.Articles
where a.Category.SomeProperty == someValue
select new DaoArtType {
    ArticleId = a.Id,
    //...
    Cat = new DaoCatType {
        CatId = a.Category.Id
        //...
    }
}
```

From here we can imagine another DAO object

```
public class DAOArticleWithCat {
    public int ArticleId {get; set;}
    //...
    public int ArticleCatId {get; set;}
    //...
    public int ArticleSubCatId {get; set;}
    //...
}
```

such an DAO object can be populated by the result of a stored procedure. But you won't get tracked entities.